# Non-state variable inside SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui, struct, var, mutable, let

I just rewatched [Demistify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) and noticed that some of the examples use variable properties inside a SwiftUI View, without using the @State property wrapper. For example (around 19.04):

```
struct PurrDecibelView: View {
    var intensity: Double

    var body: some View {
        // ...
    }
```

It does not seem to be possible to change this property from any action defined in its body. Is there any reason for choosing a `var` over `let` here?

Comment: No there isn’t. “Let” would make it correct but it doesn’t make a difference.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, I just added the time.

Comment: Should be let. Always lots of typos in these videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a reason for for choosing `var` over `let` in **the specific case you have shared**, but there could be some reasons like:

##### 1. Default value and default initializer

If you set a default value to a `let` variable, it will not be present in the default initializer of the struct. But making it var will cause it to be an optional parameter:
[image: Var Demo]

#### 2. Outside the body

Since `View` is just a protocol you conform to, there may be some reasons to have functionalities outside the `body` that you can control using `mutating func`s:

```
struct PurrDecibelView {
    var intensity: Double

    mutating func increaseIntensity() {
        intensity += 1
    }
}

extension PurrDecibelView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("")
    }
}
```

##### 3. Styleguide

Some teams and some companies prefer to always use var inside the `struct`s and only control the mutability of the initiated objects.

<sub>Not that I don't personally recommend or deny any of the above or any other reasons.</sub>

Comment: I completely missed #1, that makes sense. I thought about #2, you could have some ViewBuilder that uses this before returning the view. #3 sound plausible, but would be better with a reference to such a style guide (preferably with a rationale).

Comment: As I mentioned, In this answer, I agree or against none of them., but for the #2, imagine a normal `Rectangle` struct that someday you have decided to make it `View`-able. And about the reference, I saw this in some companies internally but I can't find a public source to share. I will update you if I can.

Comment: Extension of an existing type to conform to View doesn't have anything to do with this question (which already considers a View), but it's an interesting idea!

Comment: Yes, I did the extension to be more clear, I kept the naming to be linked with original question